# Find the largest $f$ such that $2^f\mid 1234567891011213141516$

Tags: number-theory

> Find the largest $f$ such that $2^f\mid 1234567891011213141516$

So, I'm sure the way to do this is to decompose this number into the sum of its decimal digits, but at that point, deciding the largest $f$ confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you find the first $f$ that makes $12345678910111213141516 \equiv 0 \pmod { 2^f}$ false, then the answer is one less than that $f$.

So, obviously, $f=1$ works, since your number is even.  $f=2$ also works, after you do the decimal expansion of the number.  $f=3$ doesn't work, however.  So f = 2 is your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Since $8\nmid 516$, the largest power of $2$ dividing that number is $4$.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you know the [divisibility rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) for 4 and 8?  If not, you can just divide by 2 and count how many divisions it takes to get to an odd number.  The divisibility rule says you can ignore all the upper digits, which makes the work much less.

Comment: So why didn't we stop at 6? Instead of 516?

Comment: I bet, Lerbi, that you can find a number that ends in $6$ but is divisible by $8$.

Comment: So we would be finding the largest possible number within that number that can be divisible by 2?

Comment: Huh? I don't understand, @Lerbib. By the way, are you any relation to Lerbi, who began this discussion? Your names are very similar.